# Runing and ending a Python script with sudo from inside another python script?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sudo, neopixel

I am currently working on an Raspyberry Pi Camera project where I am using an Adafruit Neopixel ring as a ringlight.
The Neopixle library needs the script to be run with sudo in order to work, but I don't really want to have to run the entire project as sudo, for one because I know sudo should only be used as much as necessary and 3 out of 300+ lines hardy seem enough to justify it. And on the other hand, the project also writes a couple of paramters to a json as a save file and all these saves needing superuser permission to edit is making testing very tedious...

I had already isolated the code needing to be run with sudo into a function `ringlight()` which I transfererd to it's own file, ringlight.py.
From my main project, I now turn on my ringlight with `os.system("sudo python ringlight.py")`
But how can I close the instance of ringlight.py from my main project without closing it to?

I already tried putting `if input() == 'q': raise SystemExit` in my ringlight.py and then sending `os.system("q")` from the main script but without the desired effect.